# Issue with bashrc file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hadoop, linux-mint

When I open the .bashrc file using gedit, or vi editor, there's nothing in it. I am on MINT trying to install Hadoop and one of the step requires editing the .bashrc file, to save the environment variable. I remember doing the same on Ubuntu, and there were contents were in it.

Can you help me get them all back? Is it possible to get them all back?

When I do `gedit ~/.bashrc` it opens to a blank page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the MINT forums, it doesn't look like MINT supplies a default .bashrc:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=130358

However, .bashrc is an optional file, so you can add whatever you want to it. Check out the bash man pages:

```
man bash
```

Also, if you setup a .bashrc file, make sure it is getting called from either .profile or .bash_profile like this:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: MINT does have a .bashrc file, but it's read-only. But thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should have one in here:: /etc/skel/.bashrc

Try copying it to your home folder:: cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc

Comment: If they don't already have this file in their home directory, chances are their distro doesn't ship with a `.bashrc` in `/etc/skel` either.

Answer (score 0):

Look for .bashrc.swap files in your home directory by doing so:

```
ls -Fa ~ | grep '*bashrc*'
```

I don't know how gedit or other programs name their swap files, but just look what comes up.
If there are no such files, you're out of luck.

Comment: By out of luck you mean OS re-installation?

Comment: What? No! .bashrc is just a configuration file for bash and not important for running the OS.

Comment: If you run the `env` command, it will display all environment variables on your screen. I'm not quite sure, what you intend to do, but maybe this will help.

Comment: This answer is apparently sort of trying to say, "if this file _used_ to exist and you somehow botched it, try looking for a backup file from your editor". The file name could also be something like `.bashrc~` (from Emacs) or a number of different temporary file names; what exactly to look for depends on which editor you are using. But the presupposition that you had this file and lost it should be spelled out (and the proper solution then would be to have backups, and restore it from there).

Comment: Also, the regex is wrong. Some `grep` implementations will silently look for a literal `*`, others will fail with "nothing to repeat". The proper regex for "something which contains `bashrc` somewhere" is simply `bashrc`.